# Finding an upper bound on a fraction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, continued-fractions

$0<\varepsilon <1$. If $n_k$ and $a_k$ are positive integers for which $$n_{k+1}=a_{k+1}n_k+n_{k-1}$$ 
Let $L\in\mathbb{N}.$ If $L>a_k \ge 3$, what's the smallest upper bound I can place on $$\frac{\varepsilon n_{k-1}^2}{n_k^{2-\varepsilon}}?$$ by taking $k$ arbitrarily large? 
All of my upper bounds have been infinite,  but I think there is hope since $n_k$ can be arbitrarily larger than $n_{k-1}$.

An attempt: I'd like to have an upper bound less than 1.
$$n_{k+1}=a_{k+1}n_k+n_{k-1}$$ so $$\frac{\varepsilon n_{k-1}^2}{(a_kn_{k-1}+n_{k-2})^{2-\varepsilon}}<1 \iff \varepsilon n_{k-1}^2<(a_kn_{k-1}+n_{k-2})^{2-\varepsilon}.$$
However, $$ (a_kn_{k-1}+n_{k-2})^{2-\varepsilon}>(a_kn_{k-1})^{2-\varepsilon}+n_{k-2}^{2-\varepsilon}$$ , so it suffices to have $$(a_kn_{k-1})^{2-\varepsilon}+n_{k-2}^{2-\varepsilon}>\varepsilon n_{k-1}^2$$
The left side is at least $(3n_{k-1})^{2-\varepsilon}+n_{k-2}^{2-\varepsilon}$

Comment: I don't think the pre-edited question had any hope because the numerator was to big. Now numerator is smaller and denominator is larger.

Comment: What sequence does $a_k$ follow, specifically, we are given $a_k$ but know nothing of $a_{k+1}$

Comment: You can set them all equal to $L$, where $L\ge 3$. But $L$ is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve $n_{k+1}=a_{k+1}\cdot n_k+n_{k-1}$ for $a_{k+1},$ so that
$$[1]\ \ a_{k+1}=\frac{n_{k+1}}{n_k}-\frac{n_{k-1}}{n_k}.$$
Assume for $n>N$ you have (shifting the index from your posted expression)
$$\frac{n_k^2}{n_{k+1}}<1.$$
Then $n_{k+1}/n_k >n_k$, while clearly $n_{k-1}/n_k<1.$
We also know that $n_k >3n_{k-1}$ so that $n_k \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty.$

But then a look at the two terms on the right of [1] shows that $a_k \to \infty$ with $k$, against your assumption that $3 \le a_k < L.$

NOTE: The question has now been rephrased with more intricate assumptions regarding the ratio of successive $n_k$, making the above answer obsolete. Still, maybe some way exists of applying the idea of the answer to get something about a bound.